# Necesito implementar alguna forma de que el usuario active el gps, Xamarin CrossPlatform PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin, app, xamarin.forms

He leido que por motivos de seguridad esta accion no se puede llevar a cabo aun asi hay aplicaciones que si lo hacen como por ejemplo Google Maps en la que si uno ingresa a la aplicacion con el gps desactivado esta aplicacion muestra una alerta con la opcion de activarlo.

Tambien lei que hay formas menos invasivas de instar al usuario a activar el gps como por ejemplo enviandolo a la pagina de configuracion. necesito implementar alguno de estas formas.

Como soy nuevo en Xamarin les pediria que referencien alguna aplicacion en github para entender el contexto completo de como se desarrolla esto.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, ahora mismo tu mejor solución es esta,

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin.

Este plugin es para Xamarin y activa la ubicación tanto en Android como en iOS, (windows phone no lo he probado), funciona muy bien, y es muy simple de usar.

Comment: Segun entiendo ese Plugin gestiona los permisos para que la app acceda a la geolocalizacion, esa funcion esta ok, lo que no he podido lograr es, si el gps esta desactivado, mostrar una alerta con un un boton para activar el gps.